# What dictates voltage levels on a PC's serial port pins?

Tags: rs232, pcie

I'm currently seeing an inconsistency between the serial ports of 2 PCs I'm working with, and can't seem to hone in on the cause. I'm trying to control an external scanner, which works perfectly fine on one machine, but not at all on the other.

All of the pins on both machines have the same voltage level (**0V** on pins 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, and **5V** on pin 6), except for 2 -- pins 3 and 7. On the "good" machine, pin 3 is normally at **-5V**, and pin 7 is normally at **5V**, whereas on the "bad" machine, pin 3 is normally at around **-11V**, and more surprisingly, pin 7 is at around **-11V** too.

I've actually taken the PCI Express to RS232 card out of the "good" machine and tried it in the "bad" machine, but still no luck -- it seems as though the problem is independent of the expansion card (I've tried many).

Does anyone have any insight into what is causing the different voltage levels? I'm not as worried about the magnitude, as one PC may be offering more power in this regard, but the RTS pin has different states on both machines.

Comment: You could check that card where the traces of that pin come from and what chip is responsible for creating them and look up that chips datasheet. All we could do is tell you how it *should* behave, but we can't tell why it isn't

Comment: As I mentioned, the same card fitted to both machines gives different results. It looks like the card has nothing to do with the problem. I'm looking to know if anything else in the PC can have a say in the normal state of the RTS pin.

Comment: and you expect us to tell you without seeing the card and circuitry involved?

Comment: No. I'm asking if anyone knows of other factors _in general_ which affect this or any other pins on a PC's COM port, as swapping the card doesn't make a difference in my case. Maybe if someone had seen this problem before, they might recall having fixed it through some underlying setting on the machine somewhere.

Comment: The thing *in general* that is responsible for the PC COMs port voltages is the PC COMs port circuitry, either onboard or in your case on an expansion card.

Comment: Hence my use of the words "other factors". I used the words "in general", not to mean "normally", as you interpreted them, but as they're used in engineering parlance -- as in, not a specific PC, but PCs _in general_.

Thank you for your input, but I'll hang on to see if anybody who has seen this problem before has any suggestions.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that COM ports are implemented all the same on PCs, while there are dozens of different implementations and approaches, not the least of difference being in an expansion card or not (being in one has been pretty uncommon in the last 30 years)

Comment: I'm not sure where you get that I'm making that assumption. On 3 occasions I've mentioned or implied that I've tried the same card in both machines. Even if the COM controller on it is implemented using little ants that carry the bits around, I'd still expect the same results on both machines (both Windows 7, and both with the same apparent COM port settings).

Comment: I would say that in general, this assumption is wrong. The card is not just some device with output(s), it has inputs too, and not only supply voltages, but also all kinds of stuff, starting from PCIe bus settings over being configured via BIOS or drivers. It can be as pscheidler said that the driver acts up, it could also be that the implementation uses some PCIe pin in the decision to set that pin to a certain value. Hence the suggestion to figure out how your card decides how to set the voltage.

Comment: Remember, I've tried multiple cards. How any one card sets the voltage turns my one smoking gun into 4-5 wild goose chases instead :-)

Comment: @pminogue Have you checked the voltages on the computers' power supplies? Do you have an RS-232 card which has convenient points where you could measure the supply voltages on that too?

Answer (score 3):

RS232 has a wide range of operation, [anything from 3 to 15V](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/215) should work, although running at a lower voltage is risky and some poorly made receivers may prefer some voltages over others.

The different polarity is a problem. Pin 7 is Request to Send, and it is a control line that means the computer requests the device to send data. It is often ignored, but it is reasonable for the line to idle low when the port is not trying to communicate. It could be that the driver has options for "flow control" which need to be adjusted. Pin 3 is the transmit line. If that had a different polarity it would be a problem because the polarity changes to indicate the start of a byte, but I see that this is not the issue.

I put a lot of blame on the driver here because it sounds like the device works on one PC but not another.

It could also be a baud rate problem. It can always be a baud rate problem.

Comment: From what I can see, with both machines side by side, baud rate and all that seem the exact same. I've tried 4-5 different cards on the machine, whereas both ports (on board and a card) on the other machine work fine. It's very odd.

Comment: @pminogue - Both are set to no flow control? Same versions of windows and drivers installed on both? If you open the port using a terminal program does the state of pin 7 change?

Comment: Things get even weirder then. On the good machine, the RTS pin gives out a short **-5V** pulse if I open (and if I keep reopening) the port, whereas on the bad machine the first opening will change the voltage to **+11V**, where it stays, and any further attempt to open the port will step it down to **-11V** for a long pulse before returning to **+11V**.

I'm not looking for anyone to solve this whole thing for me. I was mainly trying to find out if anything configurable beyond the card itself on the machine might be affecting it.

Comment: I realize I misread your original question, if only pin 7 has a different polarity, I would still guess it is a flow control issue. I've edited my answer to remove some confusion regarding pin 3.

Comment: @pminogue - That isn't that weird, it just means that the devices are saying they are not ready for data briefly while they open the connection. RTS should be high when the device is ready for communication.

Comment: Cheers for that insight. I'll look into the driver a bit, and the flow control too. It's not essential that I solve this completely, but it's more an annoyance now that I've come across it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a terminal programm and test each PC and serial card alone and both together.

To test the serial card alone you need an external loop back connection between RxD on pin 2 and Txd on pin 3. If the connection is present, you should see every character you type in the terminal programm looping back to screen. If no external connection is present no character should appear on the screen when typing. The internal loop back option of the terminal programm should be switched of. Configure the terminal programm to disregard the CTS input on pin 8 and DSR on pin 6 and use no flow control.

If each PC works alone you could connect both PCs together. Connect TxD of one side to RxD on the other side with two wires for both directions. GND on pin 5 should be connected with the third wire. Start the terminal programm on both PCs. What you type on one PC should go to the screen of the other one and vice versa. Of course both USART must be configured the same way for baud rate, number of data and stop bits and parity bit.

Good luck.

Comment: TXD and RXD pins behave normally on both. Both machines can talk happily over serial. It's the RTS pin that's causing the problem.

Comment: Look for hardware flow control. Maybe RTS is used for flow control on one PC and the other PC setting is different.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have an OS serial port configuration error. You don't say what sort of OS is involved, but if it's a Windows (7,8,10) variant then you can change the settings in the control panel/devices/Ports(Com&LPT).
The other potential problem is that some PC's have BIOS settings that enable/disable Serial and LPT ports....it could be a setting there.